# Display a pdf (or other file types) in the browser using Angular 9

Tags: angular, pdf

I have an endpoint that gives me a byte array.  It is a file.

I want to display this file in the browser.  Let's presume it's a PDF.  Is there a way in Angular 9 to get the contents of the endpoint and then show it directly in the browser?  I don't want to use any sort of plugin - I want the browser to use whatever the user has specified to open PDFs with.

It must display in the browser (presuming that that is what the user has specified).

I do NOT want the PDF to open in a new window.  Therefore, window.open cannot be called.

Has to work in IE11.

Comment: use an iframe to show the pdf.

Comment: please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310469/angular-5-display-embedded-pdf-from-byte

Comment: So is there a way to do this without having to use an iframe or other hack?